# Select locale using custom URL parameter in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to change the name of the URL parameter which tells GWT what language should load to be a custom parameter instead of "locale"?

For example instead of being:

```
http://myapp.com/?locale=en
```

it would be:

```
http://myapp.com/?language=en
```

I need to change the name because I don't have control over the final host page and the URLs from which the language will be loaded, although they have a specific parameter to choose the locale (which name is not locale, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your gwt.xml file:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.queryparam" value="language"/>
```